# How to create access control by group and permission

Tags: php, laravel, acl

I want to create ACL with group and permission where the user can also have multiple access. My application based on Laravel & Mysql.

The group is:
1. Division
2. Area
3. Site

The Permission is:
1. create
2. update
3. view
4. delete

For example :

Role ABC :

```
division   | create | update |  view  |  delete
division_a |   x    |   x    |   x    |    x
division_b |        |        |   x    |

area       | create | update |  view  |  delete
area_a     |        |        |   x    |    
area_b     |   x    |    x   |   x    |

site       | create | update |  view  |  delete
site_a     |        |        |   x    |    
site_b     |        |        |   x    |
```

Here is schema I have created :

Division

```
id|division_name
```

Area

```
id|area_name|division_id
```

Site

```
id|site_name|division_id|area_id
```

User Table

```
 id|name|email
```

Role Table

```
id|role_name|division_role|area_role|site_role
```

User Role Table

```
id|user_id|role_id
```

Please help me by discussing your best practices for schema design or is there any laravel packages that I can use to create this ACL?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: https://packalyst.com/packages/tag/acl

Comment: https://github.com/alexpechkarev/larbac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rathner then reinventing the wheel I suggest you to try out [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) or [Bouncer](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer) package. Which is highly benefitial.